# Detect if user has disabled local notifications

Tags: ios

I know there is the UIApplication method enabledRemoteNotificationTypes(), but that's for remote notifications. 
Is it possible to determine if the user has disabled notifications (i.e. for notification alert style they have selected None) for local notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name is indeed misleading, but `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` works for both local and remote notifications.

Also note that for iOS 8 and later you should use `currentUserNotificationSettings`.